# redirection from subdomain to subdirectory is not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have migrated my wordpress blog from subdomain to subdirectory.So I have implemented blog.example.com to https://www.edgrab.com/blog and everything has been working fine except few things.

1.`https://blog.example.com/post-name` is not redirecting to `https://www.example.com/blog/post-name` and giving internal server error 500 whereas  `blog.example.com` is redirecting successfully to `https://www.example.com/blog`

my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.example\.com/blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please check your error.log for info about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection from subdomain to subdirectory from .httaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain\.com/subdomains/%1
```